# How to see all the files inside a zip file using SFTP command?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, zip, sftp

I am trying to list all of the files inside remote server using SFTP. However the commands I tried so far such as unzip -l, less, zipinfo does not working with an error of "invalid command". Is there an actual way to solve this issue? I need to see which files exist inside my zip file in the remote server. SFTP connection is between my linux and windows server.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP is not a terminal application. It is a file-transfer utility.
You can't run remote commands (like unzip -l) via SFTP.

Login to the Linux server with a SSH client (using the same credentials as SFTP) and then try various zip-file utilities. Either unzip or infozip ought to work on most Linux distributions.